# На большом экране картинка не занимает всю ширину

Tags: android, xml

Все хорошо работает, только картинка не верно отображается на больших экранах, как сделать так что б она нормально отображалась?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <com.joooonho.SelectableRoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageNews"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center"
        app:sriv_left_top_corner_radius="4dip"
        app:sriv_right_top_corner_radius="4dip"
        app:sriv_left_bottom_corner_radius="4dip"
        app:sriv_right_bottom_corner_radius="4dip"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Я бы посоветовал не растягивать картинки вообще. А вдруг на каких-нибудь больших экранах она растянется так, что будет невозможно на неё смотреть? Мой совет - подгоните (т.е. уменьшите размер, если он слишком большой) картинку к высоте контейнера и центрируйте её, а если по бокам ничего нет, то в качестве фона поставьте эту же картинку, но с сильным размытием. Получится довольно красиво.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:layout_width="match_parent"` - ширина элемента равна всему доступному в родительском контейнере месту , вместо `"wrap_content"` - занимать только необходимое элементу место

Answer (score 1):

Вообще все зависит от параметра

```
android:scaleType
```

У Вас он стоит `center`, но надо отметить, что на скрине не оно. Можно использовать `"fitXY"` или `"matrix"`, тогда картинку точняк растянет на всю доступную выделенную под картинку площадь. Но пострадают пропорции картинки, что очевидно. Тут надо как-бы наезжать на картинку, чтобы без искажения пропорций она заняла все доступное место, тогда можно использовать `"fitCenter"`, но сработает это только в тех случаях и исключительно в тех, когда сама картинка физически, по разрешению, больше контейнера, в который она вставляется, но и тут не будет красиво. А если картинка окажется меньше, Вы просто получите все то же самое, как есть, только по центру, возможно с черным еще и сверху/снизу. Решением тут может быть - картинку программно увеличивать либо масштабировать сразу, как при пинч-жесте. Вобщем простого решения красиво вставить фото 10х15 в рамку 13х16 не получится никак.

Comment: Вы путаете `fitCenter` и `center` и частично `centerInside`.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас все это лежит в `ListView` то задайте одному элементу фиксированную высоту и а картинке такие параметры:

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Comment: Да, возможно путаю. Но и с `"centerCrop"` кажется будет тоже проблема, ежели картинка меньше контейнера. Ее ведь не растянет? А если картинка в 2 раза больше контейнера, что мы увидим тогда?

Comment: @Stan При `centerCrop` масштабирует сохраняя пропорции так чтобы картинка полностью заполнила отведенное ей пространство и обрежет боковушки там где картинка не впишется, см http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1846580&seqNum=2

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, похоже что `"centerCrop"` - самое оно, только у него там не показано что будет если все же картинка превышает размеры контейнера, хотя по описанию должна быть уменьшена.